# Node module errors while Ionic Serve

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic-serve

Everything working well but I don't know what happened, Now when I trying to hit Ionic Serve command it gives error and I have tried with different ionic version and node and npm version to fix the error but the issue remains same even I have tried to start from the fresh project but still no luck. I have attached the error page If anyone helps me it will be really grateful. 
Versions that I have installed in my system -

1. Node = v10.15.3
2. Npm = 6.4.1
3. Ionic = CLI 4.12.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node module folder which is inside your project then open your terminal and got to inside your project and use this following command "npm install --force" then "npm rebuild node-sass --force".

Comment: which OS you are using (windows/ubuntu/mac)? and send me  your "ionic info" output.